# SPARQL multi graph request and sort (Virtuoso 7)

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso, triplestore, named-graphs

Is it possible to easily make a `CONSTRUCT` request where I would be able to check data in different graphs AND sort them by "graph preference"?

Let's say I sell products. For each product, I may have different suppliers, so that my setup would look like this:

```
<http://data.experiment.com/product/1> <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#hasCurrencyValue> "10" <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/1> .
<http://data.experiment.com/product/1> <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#hasCurrencyValue> "8" <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/2> .
<http://data.experiment.com/product/2> <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#hasCurrencyValue> "5" <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/2> .
```

For each product specification, I want it from `<http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/1>`, then from `<http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/2>` if not found in `<http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/1>`.

This is what I've come up to:

```
CONSTRUCT 
{ 
    <http://data.experiment.com/product/1> ?p ?o .
} 
WHERE 
{ 
    GRAPH <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/1> 
    { 
        OPTIONAL 
        { 
            <http://data.experiment.com/product/1> ?p1 ?o1 . 
        }
    }
    GRAPH <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/2> 
    { 
        OPTIONAL 
        { 
            <http://data.experiment.com/product/1> ?p2 ?o2 . 
        }
    }
    BIND (IF (BOUND(?p1), ?p1, IF (BOUND(?p2), ?p2, UNDEF)) AS ?p)
    BIND (IF (BOUND(?o1), ?o1, IF (BOUND(?o2), ?o2, UNDEF)) AS ?o)
}
```

It does work pretty nice if I know what I'm looking for. Now if I consider:

```
CONSTRUCT 
{ 
    <http://data.experiment.com/product/1> ?p ?o . ?o ?cp ?co
} 
WHERE 
{ 
    GRAPH <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/1> 
    { 
        OPTIONAL 
        { 
            <http://data.experiment.com/product/1> ?p1 ?o1 .
            OPTIONAL { ?o1 ?cp1 ?co1 . }  
        }
    }
    GRAPH <http://data.experiment.com/graph/supplier/2> 
    { 
        OPTIONAL 
        { 
            <http://data.experiment.com/product/1> ?p2 ?o2 . 
            OPTIONAL { ?o2 ?cp2 ?co2 . } 
        }
    }
    BIND (IF (BOUND(?p1), ?p1,IF (BOUND(?p2), ?p2, UNDEF)) AS ?p)
    BIND (IF (BOUND(?o1), ?o1,IF (BOUND(?o2), ?o2, UNDEF)) AS ?o)
    BIND (IF (BOUND(?cp1), ?cp1,IF (BOUND(?cp2), ?cp2, UNDEF)) AS ?cp)
    BIND (IF (BOUND(?co1), ?co1,IF (BOUND(?co2), ?co2, UNDEF)) AS ?co)
}
```

Sometimes it doesn't work because I explicitly `BIND` `?o`, and `?o` may not be an Object —

> Virtuoso RDF01 Error Bad variable value in CONSTRUCT: "1532610063"
>   (tag 189 box flags 0) is not a valid subject, only object of a triple
>   can be a literal

I don't seem to find anyone trying to sort data by "graphs" and I'm struggling trying to find an "easy" way to do it.
I've tried with `SELECT` and `FROM NAMED`, but you've still to manually select data from the graph you want.

If anyone can help, it is more than welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: you can bind it once for non-literals and once for literals. both can be combined via UNION then.

Comment: by the way, you should fix this phrase: *"check datas in differents graphs dans sort them by "graph perefence" ?"*

Comment: I'm also surprised that your query is working even sometimes. you only have `OPTIONAL` patterns which are left-outer joins with empty tables in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AKSW. I don't think I can achieve what I need with union. I'll try an other way around.

Comment: You might consider [`COALESCE`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce) for your complex `BIND ... IF` clauses. I found [a nice example](https://blog.semaku.com/post/140876753748/using-coalesce-and-if-in-sparql-for-nested).

Comment: Your sample data and queries have many issues (e.g., `<data/product/1>`, `<graph:supplier2>`) which make them unusable for running any live tests. It's helpful to conform to Turtle, N-Triples, and/or N-Quads for data, and SPARQL for queries, when posting questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Update from my previous post. Each suppliers for a given Book are stored in a "default" graph.

```
# Named graph : http://data.books.com/default
@prefix book: <http://data.books.com/resource/Book/>
@prefix ns: <http://data.books.com/ns#>

book:8780953608758 ns:hasSupplier <http://data.books.com/supplier/Alpha> .
book:8780953608758 ns:hasSupplier <http://data.books.com/supplier/Beta> .


# Named graph : http://data.books.com/supplier/Alpha
@prefix book: <http://data.books.com/resource/Book/>
@prefix price: <http://data.books.com/resource/Price/>
@prefix gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

book:8780953608758 gr:hasPriceSpecification price:8780953608758_FR_EUR .
price:8780953608758_FR_EUR gr:hasCurrencyValue "10" .
book:8780953608758 dc:available 1447632000 .

# Named graph : http://data.books.com/supplier/Beta
@prefix book: <http://data.books.com/resource/Book/>
@prefix price: <http://data.books.com/resource/Price/>
@prefix gr: <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#>
@prefix dc: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

book:8780953608758 gr:hasPriceSpecification price:8780953608758_FR_USD .
price:8780953608758_FR_USD gr:hasCurrencyValue "8" .
book:8780953608758 dc:available 1547632000 .
```

The first subquery in the query bellow use the graph **http://data.books.com/default** to find and sort all our suppliers graphs for the book 8780953608758. It then matches another pattern against that graph.

```
PREFIX book: <http://data.bookeen.com/resource/Book/>

CONSTRUCT 
{
    book:8780953608758 ?p ?o . ?o ?cp ?co .
}
WHERE 
{
    {
        SELECT ?supplier 
        FROM <http://data.books.com/default>
        WHERE 
        {
            VALUES (?supplier ?priority) 
            { 
                (<http://data.books.com/supplier/Beta> 1) 
                (<http://data.books.com/supplier/Alpha> 2)   
            }
            book:8780953608758 <http://data.books.com/ns/hasSupplier> ?supplier.
        }
        ORDER BY ?priority
        LIMIT 1
    }

    GRAPH ?supplier
    {
        book:8780953608758 ?p ?o .
        OPTIONAL { ?o ?cp ?co . }
    }
}
```